# How can I pass a DOM element as a parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, dom

I want to pass the myVideo element as a parameter in the play() function, but it does not work? (It is auto-playing the video instead and the eventListener no longer works)

If I use the element directly in the function it work. So I am wondering is it ever possible to pass a DOM element as a parameter and if so is it ever used

Here is the code below:

```
// Get our elements
const myVideo = document.querySelector(".player__video");
const playButton = document.querySelector(".player__button");
console.log(myVideo);

function play(video) {

    if (video.paused) {
        video.play();
    } else {
        video.pause();
    }
}

playButton.addEventListener('click', play(myVideo))
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

```
playButton.addEventListener('click', function(){play(myVideo)})
```

You need to pass a function but instead you are passing the result of a function. JavaScript has first class functions, so get used to this thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
const myVideo = document.querySelector(".player__video");
const playButton = document.querySelector(".player__button");
console.log(myVideo);

function play(video) {

    if (video.paused) {
        video.play();
    } else {
        video.pause();
    }
}

playButton.addEventListener('click', () => play(myVideo) );
```

will works.
addEventListener requires the second parameter as a Function, but you passed a value as undefined.